# The toast message component I created in React Native is displayed only once on Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I needed a customized toast message component for my project. I created a component for this. For iOS, I can see the toast message I created every time I call the function, but on the android side, I can see it only once. what could be the reason for this? Here is my codes:

My component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DeviceEventEmitter, InteractionManager, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Label, Fiew } from '../../hooks';
import { SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE, TOAST_TYPES } from '../../constants/toast';


export default function Toast() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [messageType, setMessageType] = useState('');
  const [timeDuration, setTimeDuration] = useState(3000);

  const onNewToast = (data) => {
    setMessage(data.message);
    setMessageType(data.type);
    if (data.duration) {
      setTimeDuration(data.duration);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE, onNewToast);

    return () => {
      DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
          setMessage('');
          setMessageType('');
          setTimeDuration(3000);
        });
      }, timeDuration);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    }
  }, [timeDuration, message]);

  if (!message) {
    return null;
  }

  const backgroundColor =
    messageType === TOAST_TYPES.INFO
      ? 'bg-purple'
      : messageType === TOAST_TYPES.DANGER
      ? 'bg-red'
      : 'bg-green';

  const textColor = messageType === TOAST_TYPES.DANGER ? 'text-white' : 'text-darkest';

  return (
    <Fiew
      className={`absolute  top-[6%] self-center rounded-full z-10 p-2 ${backgroundColor}`}
      style={{ elevation: 1 }}>
      <Label translate={false} className={`font-semibold text-sm ${textColor}`}>
        {message}
      </Label>
    </Fiew>
  );
}
```

Helpers.js:

```
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
import { SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE, TOAST_TYPES } from '../../constants/toast';
const toast = {
  info: (options) => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.emit(SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE, { ...options, type: TOAST_TYPES.INFO });
  },
  success: (options) => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.emit(SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE, { ...options, type: TOAST_TYPES.SUCCESS });
  },
  danger: (options) => {
    DeviceEventEmitter.emit(SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE, { ...options, type: TOAST_TYPES.DANGER });
  }
};
export default toast;
```

This is how I call my toast message:

```
 const onCopyHandler = () => {
    Clipboard.setString(user.uid);
    toast.info({ message: 'copied!'});
  };
```

And here is my App.js:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Toast />
  <ModalHandler>
     <Content />
  </ModalHandler>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Thanks for your helps...

I was expecting my Toast message component to work like it does on iOS.